# Elastic Search: indexing dates field that has null values

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch client in Python to create index for the fields below and I am stuck on creating date index that has null values. 
I am having very hard time seeing why the index it not setting to `date` instead of `string` when there are null values present in the data. 
From the online and ES documentation research, looks like you can't index on null values. 
So, I am following this `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html` documentation to over come the problem which uses `"null_value": "NULL"`, however I have not been successful.

I have tried changing the actual date date into format like `"yyyy-MM-dd", "MM/dd/yyyy"` ... etc and many other combinations.
For the json mapping I have also tried `{"type": "strict_date"}` and `{"type": "strict_date": "MM/dd/yyyy"}`. 
Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Data:

```
  id_name,team_name,team_members,date_info,date_sub
  123,"Biology, Neurobiology ","Ali Smith, Jon Doe",5/1/2015,5/1/2015
  234,Mathematics,Jane Smith ,8/12/2016,
  345,"Statistics, Probability","Matt P, Albert Shaw",5/15/2015,5/15/2015
  456,Chemistry,"Andrew M, Matt Shaw, Ali Smith",4/12/2017,
  678,Physics,"Joe Doe, Jane Smith, Ali Smith ",5/12/2017,5/12/2017
```

JSON/PYTHON MAPPING:

```
request_body = '''
        {
            "settings" : {
              "number_of_shards": 2,
              "number_of_replicas": 1
            },

            "mappings": {
                "team": {
                    "properties": {
                        "id_name": { "type": "text"},
                        "team_name": { "type": "text"},
                        "team_members": { "type": "text"},
                        "date_info": {"type": "date","null_value": "NULL"},
                        "date_sub": {"type": "date","null_value":"NULL"}
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    '''

    res = self.es.indices.create(index=your_index_name, ignore = 400, body=request_body)
```

ERROR:

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse [date_info]')
```

Comment: Can you post your indexing request?

Answer (score 0):

In your mappings you didn't specify date format for your date fields, in this case Elastic will use built-in format, which is following - `"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"`, which means, it should be either a long number representing milliseconds from begining of the epoch or `strict_date_optional_time`, which is effectively is a **strict** format

Strict format means, that if you have date `5/12/2017`, it should be filled up to missing digits. In this case proper strict date should be `05/12/2017`

More information on date formats - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your schema for date fields must not contain `"null_value": "NULL"`.

I tried it in Kibana

```
PUT stackoverflow {
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "team": {
      "properties": {
        "id_name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "team_name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "team_members": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "date_info": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "date_sub": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then, I tried to insert data with null date info

```
POST stackoverflow/team
{
  "id_name": 341,
  "team_name": "Gogologi",
  "team_members": "Wayern",
  "date_info": null,
  "date_sub": "2014-02-01"
}
```

and to verify, I executed GET command `GET stackoverflow/team/_search`

```
{
  "_index": "stackoverflow",
  "_type": "team",
  "_id": "AWOCTEhoVu_LbUvfNt6J",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id_name": 341,
    "team_name": "Gogologi",
    "team_members": "Wayern",
    "date_info": null,
    "date_sub": "2014-02-01"
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `null_value` needs to be the **same data type** as the field. [null_value | Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html)

I set the `null_value` to a value that can be parsed by the specified `format`.

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "null_value": "01/01/0001", 
        "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, we can insert some documents.

```
POST my-index-000001/_doc
{ "date": null }
POST my-index-000001/_doc
{ "date": "01/01/0001" }
POST my-index-000001/_doc
{ "date": "31/10/2021" }
```

Now, we can search for `null_value`.

```sh
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "date": "01/01/0001"
    }
  }
}

### Response ###
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my-index-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "rY203nwBSf_8E_MJ7pyJ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : null
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my-index-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ro203nwBSf_8E_MJ9Jzy",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "01/01/0001"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But be careful that `null_value` can still be searched using the `range` query.

```sh
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "lt": "01/01/2021"
      }
    }
  }
}

### Response ###
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my-index-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "rY203nwBSf_8E_MJ7pyJ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : null
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my-index-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ro203nwBSf_8E_MJ9Jzy",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "01/01/0001"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```